# WSO2-ESB How to save the whole SOAP Envelope into a property

Tags: soap, apache-axis, esb, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I am saving the message body into a property with the following syntax

```
 <property name="MyBody" expression="$body" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

as described at      https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Synapse+XPath+Variables#SynapseXPathVariables-$axis2

I was wondering whether there is a way to save the whole envelope at once, not only the header or the body. I could not find any information about it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize the [enrich mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Enrich+Mediator) available in the wso2 ESB. Simply you mention as this and preserve your envelop in the "INIT_MSG" property and later you use it.

```
<enrich>
        <source type="envelope" clone="true"/>
        <target type="property" property="INIT_MSG"/>
</enrich>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="FirstBodyContent" expression="$body/*[1]" type="OM"/>
```

We can use this Above line for getting first Element of soap:Body

for Getting Body Content use this below line

```
<property name="BodyContent" expression="$body" type="OM"/>
```